# jsreport asp.net mvc iis no node.exe present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, pdf-generation, iis-7.5, jsreport

I am able to follow the post (http://jsreport.net/blog/rendering-pdf-from-aspnet-mvc-views) and get reports to work as expected. 
Great tool and good Job in article/tooling. Thanks!

I have an ASP.NET MVC + Web API + jsReport-mvc + embedded-server.

I'm facing following issues:

1. When application starts (i.e. app pool in IIS starts), if I look at Task Manager, there are three node.exe processes created. Is it normal?
2. After sometime, node.exe is no more running. After this, if I hit Print url, I get following error:
   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:2000

My questions are:

a/ Am i missing something here?

b/ Should not jsreport first check and start node.exe if it is not already running?

Comment: the answer was posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jsreport/embedded/jsreport/IluFHA9spB4/uWT50aOkhKEJ